# Displaying subitems on mvc 3 form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, list

(warning newbie)
I am using codefirst entity framework (with MVC3) and trying to display a list of steps and its associated questions. Not sure why my syntax is throwing an exception "the ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.":

```
@model IEnumerable<COPSGMIS.Models.Step>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Questionaire";
}

<h2>Questionaire</h2>
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Questionaire", "Question", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SignupForm" }))
   {
       <div>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
              <fieldset class="wizard">
                <legend class="wizard">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</legend>
                @foreach (var question in item.Questions)
                //*** item.Questions is throwing an exception  ****
                {
                <label for="question">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => question.QuestionText)</label>
                <input id="question" type="text" /> 
                }
              </fieldset>
            }            
        <p>
            <input id="SaveAccount" type="button" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </div>
   }
```

My model:

```
public int StepID { get; set; }
        public int ReviewID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int StepOrder { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
```

My controller:

```
var steps = from b in db.Steps
                            orderby b.StepOrder
                            select b;
                return View(steps.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When item.Questions is access, EF will try to hit the database to grab the questions for that item.  If the context has been disposed, it will fail.  Since you'll be looping through the questions in your view, I'd suggest adding them to your initial query using "Include".

```
var steps = from b in db.Steps.Include(s => s.Questions)
            orderby b.StepOrder
            select b;

return View(steps.ToList());
```